# Site won't run - Could not load file or assembly 'dtSearchNetApi4.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dtsearch

I have a C# Framework web project that we have been using for years.  When running in debug we get:

> Could not load file or assembly 'dtSearchNetApi4.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

We encountered this issue originally a few years back, but fixed it by checking "Use the 64 bit version of IIS for web sites and projects" in Options.  However, I just got a new machine, installed VS22, pulled down the project, and...it returned.  It works fine on my old machine, on others' machines, on servers to which we publish...just not when I run through IIS Express on my new machine.

I am using the 64-bit version as indicated on their site, I have checked all the settings, made sure the file was pulled down, is in the location from which it is linked in references, is in bin. What might be happening?  Both my old and new machines are Windows 10, 64-bit processors.

Comment: See following : https://support.dtsearch.com/dts0217.htm?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng will edit to indicate, but I am using the 64-bit version

Comment: The link I provided said "HOW TO USE 64 BIT".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using DUMPBIN to find the dependencies for dtSearchNetApi4.DLL, I discovered that there was a dependency that was from the VS 2012 [Visual C++ Redist Package](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679)