# Issue with dtSearchNetApi4 64 bit DLL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dtsearch

Earlier I had a 32-bit application and I am in the process of converting it into a 64-bit application.
Earlier I had a dtSearchNetApi4 32-bit DLL. Currently, I have replaced it with 64-bit DLL.
I am using Visual Studio 2019 and I changed my web application platform target to anycpu
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am a bit unclear on dt search support documentation https://support.dtsearch.com/faq/dts0217.htm.

Note:- This application is hosted in IIS I have changed the Enable 32bit application to false and loaded the application then the application loaded without any issues.
[image]

Can anyone please explain why unable to run using visual studio and how can I resolve it?

update :- I changed my web application platform target to x64 and I got the below error
[image]

Comment: Check in the bin folder of project and verify the date of the missing dll.  It should be in the debug and/or release folder of the main project and the date should be the last time it was compiled.

Comment: @jdweng those dlls are up to date. no issues with it.

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70699664/site-wont-run-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-dtsearchnetapi4-dll-or-one-of

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)